# ODM/ORM for PouchDB in JavaScript

Tags: node.js, couchdb, pouchdb, offlineapps, offline-browsing

I'm interested in using PouchDB for a offline-first mobile application (Cordova) and I'm wondering if there is any leightweight ORM/ODM for PouchDB written in JavaScript. Couldn't find one.

Is PouchDB the most common way to implement "offlinability" in JavaScript? Or are there other better ways to do that (without going native).

Comment: There's that [TypeScript ORM](https://www.npmjs.com/package/slothdb?activeTab=dependencies).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another one is https://github.com/iyobo/pouchorm, claiming to be 'The definitive ORM for working with PouchDB. Native support for Typescript.'

At the time of writing it appears to be still actively developed.

I did some research and consider [PouchDB](https://pouchdb.com/) and [RxDB](https://rxdb.info/) the two most feasible options if you go for open source and want to avoid larger costs for the servers.  There still is [CouchBase](https://www.couchbase.com/) which provides libraries for many languages.

Comment: Do you mean PouchORM and RxDB?

Answer (score 1):

PouchORM (https://github.com/iyobo/pouchorm) is a solid option.

It's light weight and yet super-functional.
It has all the features I would care for when using pouchdb; namely it's simplicity, data validation and it's cool use of separating data across a single DB using collections.

The collections are also indexed by their type so this does not affect speed.